# Adaptive card conditional validation

Tags: json, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card like below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "text": "Order Page",
      "wrap": true,
      "style": "heading"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "label": "Item",
      "id": "item",
      "isRequired": true,
      "errorMessage": "Name is required"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "label": "Quantity",
      "isRequired": true,
      "errorMessage": "Location is required",
      "id": "quantity"
    },   
    
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Cancel",
      "data": {
        "buttonClicked": "cancel"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit",
      "data": {
        "buttonClicked": "submit"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using this in a chat bot.

Here the user has to enter the item name & the quantity if they wish to order by clicking `Submit` button.

On the other hand if they change their mind and not wish to order, they can just click `Cancel` button.

However, since I have `"isRequired": true,` the card starts to validate even when the user clicks `Cancel` button. So, how to do the validation ONLY when `Submit` button is clicked but not when `Cancel` button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution available. You can use the property "associatedInputs" and set it to "none".

```
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Cancel",
      "associatedInputs": "none",
      "data": {
        "buttonClicked": "cancel"
      }
    },
```

You may find the relevant documentation here:
https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html